# Heap Issue while deleting the structure

Tags: c, structure

When I try to delete the structure that I got from Queue.It will throw runtime heap error.

here is my sample.

```
   /* "Message_content" structure hold the content of message and body. */
   typedef struct msgContent
   {
     char *message;
     char *body;
     struct msgContent *nextptr;
   }Message_content;

static Message_content *frontptr;
static Message_content *rearptr;

Message_content* msgContent;
msgContent = QueueDelete();
free(msgContent); //**error happens while calling this function**.
```

Here is my QueueDelete() function in c.

```
static Message_content* QueueDelete()
{
Message_content *tempMsgContent = NULL;

if(frontptr == NULL)
{
}
else if(frontptr==rearptr)
{
    tempMsgContent = frontptr;
    tempMsgContent->nextptr = NULL;
    frontptr = rearptr = NULL;
}
else
{
    tempMsgContent = frontptr;

    frontptr = frontptr->nextptr;
            tempMsgContent->nextptr = NULL; // rectify the problem said by philong
}
return tempMsgContent;
}
```

**EDIT**
Add Queue Insert Function which will give meaning to my code.

here is my Queue Insert function in c

```
  static int QueueInsert(char *message ,char *body)
  {
    Message_content *tempMsgContent  = (Message_content*) malloc(sizeof(Message_content*));
   if(rearptr == NULL && frontptr == NULL) 
   {
    rearptr = tempMsgContent;
    rearptr->message = message;
    rearptr->body = body;
    rearptr->nextptr=NULL;
    frontptr = rearptr;
    return 1;
   }
    rearptr->nextptr = tempMsgContent;
    rearptr = rearptr->nextptr;
    rearptr->body = body;
    rearptr->message = message;
    rearptr->nextptr = NULL;
    return 1;
    }
```

Comment: incompletely specified -- what's frontptr for instance?

Comment: You do set `frontptr` and `rearptr` to `NULL` before manipulating the pointers?

Comment: @pileborg: I initialized frontptr and rearptr as static variables.so they will be initialized as NULL.

Comment: You cannot guarantee it. They're supposed to be initialized as NULL, but it's always good practice to initialize them yourself.
For example, you could have a problem with tour `QueueInsert` if`rearptr` is NULL and `frontptr`is not NULL.

Comment: I have just remembered the existence of a marvellous piece of software, it's called valgrind and it might help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might be your problem:

```
tempMsgContent = frontptr;
tempMsgContent->nextptr = NULL;
frontptr = frontptr->nextptr;
```

You set the `nextptr` of `tempMsgContent` to `NULL`, which is good, but `frontptr` and `tempMsgContent` still point to the same memory location!

Set the `nextptr` to `NULL` *after* changing the `frontptr`.

**Edit** Checking through your `QueueInsert` code, I see this line:

```
Message_content *tempMsgContent  = (Message_content*) malloc(sizeof(Message_content*));
```

What that does is allocate memory enough for a *pointer* (`sizeof(Message_Content*)`)! You should use `sizeof(Message_Content)` without the asterisk. This will certainly mess upp your heap!

Comment: @PileBorg: Even I Update your changes.The same Error remains.

Comment: @PileBorg: Heap Error throws while calling free(messagecontent);

Comment: @user1004807 Does it happen all the time? For the first node?

Comment: @pileBorg : I checked it for first node.It seems that it is happening for first node.

Comment: @pileBorg: Awesome, Now my code is working fine.Thanks for your Info.

Comment: Nicely spotted, +1, Joachim.
@user1004807, as I mentioned before (your answer's comment section) valgrind would point this kind of error out.